# Google play games leaderboard shows different values for 'today' and 'all time'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-games, leaderboard

I'm having a weird problem with a leaderboard I created.
I asked a couple of people to play my game today.
After they played it I went to check the leaderboard, to see if their score made it there.
Some did, some didn't, which is weird by itself, but that could be something with my code.

What I assume can't be something with my code is the fact that different values (and also different players) made it either to the 'today' section of the leaderboard or to the 'all-time' section.

Pictures:

[all-time section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckono.jpg)

[today section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfKIK.jpg)

I can't understand why this is happening.

Comment: I don't understand either, I see the scores are different, but I don't see anything to debug or troubleshoot.

Comment: @Eddge Well, I didn't include any code because as I said I don't think it has something to do with my code. I use [play-games-plugin-for-unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) to send the score to the leaderboard and for some reason on their side, they decide to put it in different sections. Basically, the only code I do is this: Social.ReportScore();

Comment: Well @FakeMelon unfortunately there isn't much we can do to help you then, we have no information about how you are posting to your leaderboards, we have no information on how you are determining which boards to show where, so we really have no way to tell you if it is a bug in your code or something in that repo.  Maybe try making a post on the github to see if anyone else is having the same problems.  If not then it is probably something you are(or aren't) doing.

Comment: @Eddge I understand what you are saying, I was just hoping, as you said, that I might find someone here who experienced the same problem and knows what's the solution.
I'll go do what you suggested, thank you.